# How to group by parent and collect all property values of child in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

I want to collect all shows and their associated genres together. GENRES are child relationship of SHOWS

[Sample gemlin graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNy7k.png)
So that the output is something similar to:

```
"1" [a,b]
"2" [c,d]
```

Sample graph: https://gremlify.com/x8i8stszn2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `project()` [step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step) within Gremlin like this:

```
g.V("2789").out('WATCHED').hasLabel('SHOW').
project('show', 'genre').
  by('NAME').
  by(out('HAS_GENRE').values('NAME').fold())
```

This will return your data formatted like this this:

```
[
  {
    "show": 1,
    "genre": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  },
  {
    "show": 2,
    "genre": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ]
  }
]
```